# Which version of python is supported in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to setup tensorflow for python version 3.7.1 which was not supported and ended up wasting half Sunday.
I want to know which versions of python does tensorflow supports?

Comment: Did you visit Tensorflow official web link?

Comment: Please check this thread. Someone raised the same issue. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022

Answer (score 6):

From the official [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system):

> Requires Python 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6

**Edit:**

It [looks](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location) like Python 3.7 is now supported with TensorFlow 1.13+

Therefore, requires Python 3.4+ for TensorFlow 1.13+

Answer (score 3):

As of 11 Dec I found this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu

Windows CPU:

| Version | Python version |
| --- | --- |
| tensorflow-2.3.0 | 3.5-3.8 |
| tensorflow-2.2.0 | 3.5-3.8 |
| tensorflow-2.1.0 | 3.5-3.7 |
| tensorflow-2.0.0 | 3.5-3.7 |

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow, for now only works with Python 3.6, 3.7 support is still in active development, make sure to install python 3.6 and try to set it up again, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am only posting the question and i am only giving the answer for it.
**TENSORFLOW IS NOT SUPPORTED FOR PYTHON 3.7.X**. 
Please do not waste time even on trying also 
It will throw an error on "pywrap_internal.py"
From Anaconda create conda environment and install tensorflow package
Try importing it.
Hope it helps.