# how to solve incompatible in conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I just begin with conda and i am creating an environment but i get an incompatible problem, I don't know how to fix it.
here my list of package in this environment.

```
(test_phobert) meo@meo-Latitude-E6540:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/meo/anaconda3/envs/test_phobert:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_pytorch_select           0.2                       gpu_0  
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.10.0                   py38_0  
aiohttp                   3.6.2            py38h7b6447c_0  
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0  
async-timeout             3.0.1                    py38_0  
attrs                     20.2.0                     py_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blinker                   1.4                      py38_0  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h7b6447c_1000  
c-ares                    1.16.1               h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2020.7.22                     0  
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0  
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0  
cffi                      1.14.3           py38he30daa8_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cryptography              3.1.1            py38h1ba5d50_0  
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0  
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0  
filelock                  3.0.12             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0  
google-auth               1.22.1                     py_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2  
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0  
gperftools                2.7                  h767d802_2    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.31.0           py38hf8bcb03_0  
h5py                      2.10.0           py38hd6299e0_1  
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0  
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
importlib-metadata        2.0.0                      py_1  
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254  
joblib                    0.17.0                     py_0    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libprotobuf               3.13.0               hd408876_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
markdown                  3.3                      py38_0  
mkl                       2020.2                      256  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py38h23d657b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h0573a6f_0  
multidict                 4.7.6            py38h7b6447c_1  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
ninja                     1.10.1               hc9558a2_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.1           py38hbc911f0_0  
numpy-base                1.19.1           py38hfa32c7d_0  
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1h               h7b6447c_0  
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0  
packaging                 20.4               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
perl                      5.30.3               h516909a_1    conda-forge
pip                       20.2.3                   py38_0  
protobuf                  3.13.0           py38he6710b0_1  
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py38_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0  
python                    3.8.5                h7579374_1  
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.4.0           cuda101py38h02f0884_0  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
regex                     2020.9.27        py38h1e0a361_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0  
rsa                       4.6                        py_0  
sacremoses                0.0.43             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.5.2            py38h0b6359f_0  
sentencepiece             0.1.91           py38hbf85e49_3    conda-forge
setuptools                50.3.0           py38hb0f4dca_1  
six                       1.15.0                     py_0  
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0  
tensorboard               2.2.1              pyh532a8cf_0  
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0  
tensorflow                2.2.0           mkl_py38h6d3daf0_0  
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           mkl_py38h5059a2d_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh208ff02_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py38_1  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
tokenizers                0.8.1rc2                 pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.50.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
transformers              3.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.10                    py_0  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38h7b6447c_1  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yarl                      1.6.0            py38h7b6447c_0  
zipp                      3.3.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

when i try command `conda update --all` i get

```
(test_phobert) meo@meo-Latitude-E6540:~$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::transformers==3.3.1=py_0
failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::transformers==3.3.1=py_0
failed
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package tensorflow conflicts for:
transformers -> tensorflow
tensorflow

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
tensorflow -> python=2.7 -> ca-certificates
```

Anybody can explain for me what mean of this part:

```
Package tensorflow conflicts for:
transformers -> tensorflow
tensorflow

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
tensorflow -> python=2.7 -> ca-certificates
```

and how to i can fix that problem ??? Thank you so much.

Comment: with which python version did u tried to install tensorflow?

Comment: iam pretty sure you got python version conflict since tensorflow works only with some python versions with specific tensorflow versions, check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513388/which-version-of-python-is-supported-in-tensorflow

Comment: also see this official tensorflow website https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system

Comment: The conflicts output lists every package that has two or more packages directly depending on it; that is, most of what is emitted is fine. One inconsistency I see is `tokenizers` was install through PyPI, but `transformers` requires a version from Conda. I'd start by removing the PyPI version and installing with Conda. Not sure that's the issue though.

Comment: @CYREX i use `conda install tenforflow`

Comment: @CYREX I disagree. That's an old issue. Anaconda's TF supports Python 3.8, and everything listed in the environment seems to be Python 3.8. I do find the `tensorflow -> python=2.7` odd. Perhaps a `conda clean` might be in order.

Comment: visit tensorflow website, maybe u r missing smthg.

Comment: @Khánh Đinh Ngọc has the above comment resolved your issue?

Comment: Try installing via mamba and all at once (i.e. in the `mamba create` command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/13697228